# Angular http error status 0

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I have two routes in my backend, they look like this

```
router.get('/advstats/:player', (req,res)=>{
    Player.find({PLAYERCODE: req.params.player}, (err,docs)=>{
        res.status(200).json(docs[0].advstats);
    })
})
router.get('/:player/:stat',(req, res)=>{
    Player.find({PLAYERCODE: req.params.player}, 'gamelogs', (err,docs)=>{
        let data = [];
        for (let game of docs[0].gamelogs){
            console.log(game)
            data.push({date:game["GAME_DATE"],stat:game[req.params.stat]})
        }
        res.status(200).json(data)
    })
});
```

I'm trying to access the routes through angular, and while the second one works without issue, I'm getting a http error status 0 for the first route. Definitely not a CORS issue; checked that multiple times, and the second route works fine.

The frontend code looks like

```
  getData(player: string, stat: string) {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/advstats/'+player).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/' + player + '/' + stat).subscribe((res: PlayerstatModel[]) => {
      this.createChart(res);
    });
  }
```

My console output is

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ 0 ()
core.js:1542 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

Both routes work fine in the browser, but not in Angular.

Is there something obvious I'm missing, as I don't see why the first route refuses to work.

Comment: If you check in the network tab of the developer tools (instead of the console), can you see what status is being returned? Also, can you check the response headers to make sure you're sending necessary the CORS headers?

Comment: I'm getting an ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT in the network tab.


Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * is present on the response headers when loading from a browser. No headers sent when loading through angular.

Comment: It's my damn adblock. I wonder whats triggering it. "stats" perhaps.

Thanks for insight on how to debug.

Comment: First catch the error properly so that we can understand what exact error you are getting. See the angular documentation for that. If you are getting CORS origin error you should change your server code to allow http call from different origin.